# Recreate existing software filter from example

Tags: photo-editing, effect, reverse-engineering

I'm new here, have been reading around for weeks and would like to ask a question myself now.

Yesterday a friend showed me these photos. I'm really charmed by the effect/filter used and am trying to re-create it myself but having a bit of a hard time.

The photos look kind of flat/gray. Like there's some mist or haze filter used.
I tried

- upping the curves in Photoshop
- making the color temperature more green/yellow
- desaturating

but so far I didn't come close to the effect below.

Can anyone help me by saying what you think is done here?
Thanks for your time and effort! :)

[image]

Comment: Instagram or something of that nature?

Comment: What do you mean by "upping the curves"?

Comment: Take your shots with a flash in a nightclub. Lower the contrast and boost saturation in post.

Comment: Thanks guys. With upping the curves I meant I tried dragging the curves-line up to get the darks lighter.

Comment: This question could really use a description of the effect in the title.

Comment: Saturation has nothing to do with this pictures. In the picture number 5 there is a lot of red because of the nightclub's lights. @Frederique: try to use "Color balance" after you removed some contrast from the photos and added a bit of vibrance

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing warm highlights and cool shadows. I opened the image in Photoshop and sampled a few areas that seemed like they were neutral in the original scene (blacks, grays whites). Its hard to be exact because I am only assuming the original color, plus there looks to be a lot of color filtration on the room lights.

I sampled the guy in image #4's (white?) t-shirt at #d7beb9
The ash shirt in #3 at (#b2aea3)
And the black shirt in #3 at (#463c45) kind of purple

I then took your image and tried to get it "normal" with a levels adjustment for a test.

I used this gradient setup to put it close to the way you had it:

Location 0%: #6f5a68

Location 92%: #f3dbc2

[image: Gradient map]

Set the adjustment layer to 50%

This will get you in the ballpark. You can adjust the brightness and saturation of the gradient stop colors, I think the hues I listed will be close to what you want.

Comment: Cool shadows? Image 3 and 6 looks like having their blacks processed with a decent amount of yellow...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say maybe try a gradient map layer with a dark gray as the lower colour and an average green-yellow (or pink-red for some pictures, like the two leftmost ones) as the upper colour, then play with the opacity, maybe 10 to 20%.

I'm not able to check right now, I'll try it later and update the answer with more precise values.

Answer (score 0):

The key changes that I see immediately are:

- White balance (slightly warm)
- Black levels (quite high)
- Faux cross-processing (Red s-curve, Blue upside down s-curve, slightly higher green lows)
- Vignetting

That should get you close.

Comment: I do not see proof of vignetting. The images are also shot with a wide and fast lens -- there's lots of great ambient light.